# How to prevent scintillation (antialiasing artifacts) in openGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, antialiasing, mipmaps

Here is a quote from openGL Super Bible (5th edition, Page No. 208):

```
The first is an effect called scintillation (aliasing artifacts) that appears 
on the surface of objects rendered very small on-screen compared to the 
relative size of the texture applied. Scintillation can be seen as a sort of 
sparkling that occurs as the sampling area on a texture map moves 
disproportionately to its size on the screen. The negative effects of 
scintillation are most noticeable when the camera or the objects are in motion.
```

I am currently facing the exact same problem, (I am loading an image 4912 x 3264 pixels) and doing some affine transformations like rotation and translation. It is showing fuzziness especially where the texture loaded has white pixels (that might not be a general observation but I am observing this). Here is the code:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image->width,image->height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
//gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_RGB,image->width,image->height, GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image->imageData);
```

The animations are smooth everything is going perfect except for those spoilers.
Can somebody help me with improving this situation as I am developing an application which will have great concerns for such stuff?

Also if after using `glTexImage2D`, if I use `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, it gives `segmentation fault (core dump)`. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: you are on the right track. Mipmaps would ameliorate the situation regarding the texture artifacts. It is only defined for power of two sized textures though.

Comment: @DanielFlassig: Nonsense. Mipmaps work for arbitrarily sized textures. Don't pass misinformation along.

Comment: @NicolBolas: sorry, then my information is outdated. It used to be that way (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml) I'll check the new spec.

Comment: @Daniel: He didn't ask about OpenGL ES. Desktop GL hasn't had this restriction since 2.0.

Comment: Do a `cout << glGenerateMipmap`. Function might not be mapped.

Comment: Also consider using anisotropic filtering. Fairly simple to enable once you have verified support for `GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic`.

Answer (score 1):

If using OpenGL ES/WebGL, make sure the texture is sized power of two. Otherwise mipmap generation or texture filtering is not working properly, causing the artifacts.

Source: http://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml

Comment: I'm adding this as an answer, since I completely missed the mention of this in the question's comments and it would have saved me hours of figuring out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're calling a rendering function with wrong buffer objects, not enough data to read from, or some other very odd state, OpenGL should not *crash*. So there's some form of driver bug happening here.

There was a very old issue with ATI drivers, where `glGenerateMipmap` would fail if you did not call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` first. I have no idea if that would help you here, but you could have a go.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely it's an OpenGL driver bug causing the crash.  Are you using a library like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net) for calling functions, and haven't verified those functions are supported?  If so, then you're calling through a NULL pointer  On Linux `glGenerateMipmap` is a "newer" function which isn't available for direct library linking, unless you get its function pointer (e.g., using `glXGetProcAddress`).

Comment: I found that enabled after the call to glGenerateMipmap(), fixed to be done before, put a "cout<<" (in c++) before and after this call, it crashed again exactly at the call

Comment: @radical7 can you tell what will be the argument for glXGetProcAddress() in this case?

Comment: @activatedGeek It's just the quoted name of the OpenGL function.  For this example, you'd add code like `PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAPPROC myGenerateMipmap = glXGetProcAddress( "glGenerateMipmap" );`  The variable type (e.g., `PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAPPROC`) is defined in *glext.h*). If the function pointer returned is *NULL*, that function is unavailable with that OpenGL context.

Comment: @activatedGeek: Or you could just use an actual [OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys, I would like to answer, I found a solution:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

Setting this as the parameter of the texture is working close to perfect! I don't know if this is the best option but it works great.

But now one catch:
while loading the texture, it does not work using (it gives a whole WHITE fill instead of image texture):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image->width,image->height, 0, GL_BGR, 
GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
```

You need to use the `gluBuild2DMipmaps()` call. While thinking upon it, I am somehow trying to justify why it is not working but I would really want if someone can comment on it.

Comment: Update: using glTexImage2D() and then building mipmaps using gluBuild2DMipmaps() does it!

Comment: gluBuild2DMipmaps will overwrite your texture. So this is probably not really what you intended. Also gluBuild2DMipmaps will rescale your image to a power of 2 which is unneccessary with OpenGL-2 and onward.

Comment: but if I don't use gluBuild2DMipmaps(), using the above parameter to correct those artifacts does not work. It gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you initialize the advanced OpenGL functions? Anything OpenGL-1.2 must be loaded at runtime first, otherwise you can't use it. This happens through the so called *extension mechanism* – the are helper libraries like GLEW doing the legwork.